# history.push is slow to reload page when adding a new record

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux-firebase

I'm pretty new to react and redux so this may be a silly question but I'll ask anyway as its driving me nuts and I want to fix it:

I have a LIST page which shows a list of records from Firebase Firestore.  I'm loading that list as a connected state object using react-redux-firestore.  Loading of the page with about 325 records in the Firestore database takes about 1.5 seconds.  I could implement paging or similar as there will be some tables with even more records but for now this is what I have.

On the LIST page, I have a button which does a history.push to a NEWRECORD page where a user can enter values into a form and click SAVE.  When SAVE is clicked, the add record (redux) action is called and the record is saved to Firebase.  All of this works fine - no issues thus far.  The problem comes to view in the next step.  After the save, the same click handler then does a history.push back to the LIST page.  The browser does redirect to the page, the newly created record is shown immediately but it takes 8-10 seconds to render the rest of the records.  This is super annoying and makes it appear that all records have somehow been deleted for a few seconds.

So I'd love for someone to explain why a re-rendering takes longer than the initial loading and how to improve things which I'm sure must be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the rest of the records will be coming from Firebase directly and not coming from redux store ?  I'm not sure .
Or If thats not the case try to enclose rest of the records in if() and then check .